# How do I get all data from a form using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've the following markup.

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="weekdays" name="wednesday[]" v-model="wed.selected" id="wednesday" type="checkbox"> Wed &nbsp; &nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="weekdays" name="thursday[]" v-model="thu.selected" id="thursday" type="checkbox"> Thu &nbsp; &nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
```

Similarly for all other days of the week. And in the Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#provider',
    data: {
        mon: {selected: false, day: 'Mondays'},
        tue: {selected: false, day: 'Tuesdays'},
        wed: {selected: false, day: 'Wednesdays'},
        thu: {selected: false, day: 'Thursdays'},
        fri: {selected: false, day: 'Fridays'},
        sat: {selected: false, day: 'Saturdays'},
        sun: {selected: false, day: 'Sundays'},
        weekends: {selected: false, day: 'Weekends'},
        weekdays: {selected: false, day: 'Weekdays'},
        fromTime: '',
        toTime: '',
        selectedDays:[{
            days : [],
            from: '',
            to:''
        }]

    },
    methods: {
        addAvailability: function() {
            if(this.mon.selected)
            {
                var days = [];
                days.push(this.mon.day);
                this.selectedDays['days'].push(days);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But this seems not working. What I'm trying to do here is when I click on a button, I want to add all checked days and time in to a variable `selectedDays` and add it to a hidden input field (json serialize the data).But what I've tried is not working well.

Can anybody direct me to the right direction? I've spent 3 days and I couldn't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a computed variable.  In your vue component:

```
computed:{
  selectedDays:function(){
    var days = [];
      if(mon.selected)
        days.push('mon');
      if(tues.selected)
        days.push('tues')
      //do for each day

      return days;
  }
}
```

Now every time you access the `selectedDays` variable, it will be automatically updated.  No need to check it on-submit, just `v-model` it to your hidden input, or submit the `selectedDays` variable directly using ajax

Comment: So, if I check a date, the `selectedDays` will be an array with `[mon, tue']` etc. What if I need to pass the time also along with this `variable`? Also, how can I repeat this again so that I can add another set of values to a hidden field?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
//HTML
<div id='example-3'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="jack">Jack</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="john">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="mike">Mike</label>
  <br>
  <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
</div>
```

and for js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#example-3',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

This is straight from the documentation. it will push all selected checkbox's value into the chackedNames array

Answer (score 0):

not sure what `weekends` or `weekdays` are for but here is a working example

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#provider',
    data: {
        days: [
            {name: 'Mondays',    selected: false, from: '', to:''},
            {name: 'Tuesdays',   selected: false, from: '', to:''},
            {name: 'Wednesdays', selected: false, from: '', to:''},
            {name: 'Thursdays',  selected: false, from: '', to:''},
            {name: 'Fridays',    selected: false, from: '', to:''},
            {name: 'Saturdays',  selected: false, from: '', to:''},
            {name: 'Sundays',    selected: false, from: '', to:''},
        ],
        weekends: {selected: false, day: 'Weekends'},
        weekdays: {selected: false, day: 'Weekdays'},
    },
    computed: {
        selectedDays: function() {
            return this.days.filter(function(item) {
                return item.selected;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="provider">
  <div v-for="day in days">
    <label :for="day.name">
      <input type="checkbox" name="days" :id="day.name" :value="day.name" :checked="day.selected" v-model="day.selected"> {{day.name}}
      <input type="text" v-model="day.from">
      <input type="text" v-model="day.to">
    </label>
  </div>
  <hr>
  {{selectedDays}}
</div>
```

more examples

http://codepen.io/ctf0/pen/LbKYjg

http://codepen.io/ctf0/pen/JbQEZa

http://codepen.io/ctf0/pen/GNbrGK